# While starting a new project in RStudio, Blogdown gives a gsub missing ')' error

Tags: r, rstudio, blogdown

I am new to Blogdown and when I try to create a new project it gives me this error

```
Just a few more steps and you're ready to go:

1. Download a theme into the same-named folder.
   Choose a theme from https://themes.gohugo.io/, or
   create your own with the "hugo new theme <THEMENAME>" command.
2. Perhaps you want to add some content. You can add single files
   with "hugo new <SECTIONNAME>\<FILENAME>.<FORMAT>".
3. Start the built-in live server via "hugo server".

Visit https://gohugo.io/ for quickstart guide and full documentation.
trying URL 'https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium/archive/master.zip'
downloaded 115 KB

Error in gsub(pattern, val, transformed, ignore.case = TRUE) : 
  invalid regular expression '\$options(internet.info\b', reason 'Missing ')''
```

I have Windows-10 and RStudio Version 1.1.456

Comment: you can always [E D I T](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52666976/edit) your question and add information. No need to write comments.

Comment: Yes, my `knitr` and `blogdown` are up to date

Comment: Sounds like the issue https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2055, but I have no idea what this error message means or why it happens. Perhaps give the preview version a try? https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/